# Plotting a function over a region

Tags: plotting

I want to plot $f(x,y)=\max(x,y)$ over this region $y > -3x + 9 $, $y > -x + 5$, $y > -1/3x + 3, x \leq 6 $ and $ y \leq 7$.

I've seen some answers, but nothing that could be applied to my case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In Mathematica 10 and later there's also the undocumented form `Plot3D[fun[x,y], {x,y} \[Element] someRegion]` where `someRegion` would be an `ImplicitRegion[...]` in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do so is to use the `RegionFunction` option.

```
Plot3D[Max[x, y], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 7}, 
       RegionFunction -> 
         Function[{x, y, z}, 
          y>-3x+9 && y>-x+5 && y>-x/3+3 && x<6 && y<7
         ]
       ]
```

Comment: @yhbs many thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

Following @Szabolcs (I hope he does not mind) comments for completeness:

we can define

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[y > -3 x + 9 && y > -x + 5 && y > -x/3 + 3 && x < 6 && y < 7, {x, y}]
```

Then

```
RegionPlot[ir]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
Plot3D[Max[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ir]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or

```
ContourPlot[Max[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ir, PlotPoints -> 50,
 ColorFunction -> "LightTemperatureMap"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]